# Rocket League won't start "kernelbase.dll" error

Tags: technical-issues, windows, rocket-league

```
Faulting application name: RocketLeague.exe, version: 1.0.10897.0, time stamp: 0x6270632d

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1706, time stamp: 0x458acb5b

Exception code: 0x00000001

Fault offset: 0x0000000000034fd9

Faulting process id: 0x1aac

Faulting application start time: 0x01d8762e05139258

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Epic Games\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe

Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll

Report Id: e71f5ed5-8107-45f0-803f-4ba6389980df

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.technewstoday.com/rocket-league-wont-launch/

Comment: There's a few suggestions in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/p2jg25/cant_start_rocket_league_kernelbasedll_problem/)